# How to generate a random quadratic function in python

Tags: python, random

I'm attempting to create a random quadratic function to the 2nd degree in python that returns the same result every time.
Something along the lines of:

```
funk = lambda i : random.randint(0,10)*i**2 + random.randint(0,10)*i + random.randint(0,10)
```

The problem here is that calling x(5) two different times will have 2 potentially different results. Is it possible to generate a function that has the same result every time, or should I just do something like:

```
m2 = random.randint(0,9)
m1 = random.randint(0,9)
b = random.randint(0,9)
funk = lambda i : m2*i**2 + m1*i + b
```

and assign a new random number to globals m2,m1, and b every time I run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to randomize coefficients only once, then save them somewhere and reuse for the following computations of the same function.

A class instance is ideal for this:

```
class RandomQuadratic:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = random.randint(0,10)
        self.b = random.randint(0,10)
        self.c = random.randint(0,10)
    def __call__(self,x):
        return self.a*x**2+self.b*x+self.c

f = RandomQuadratic()
f(5)
f(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the second approach, but just chuck it into a function. :)

```
>>> import random
>>> def random_quadratic():
...     m2 = random.randint(0,9)
...     m1 = random.randint(0,9)
...     b = random.randint(0,9)
...     funk = lambda i : m2*i**2 + m1*i + b
...     return funk
...
>>> foo = random_quadratic()
>>> foo(1)
25
>>> foo(1)
25
>>> foo(1)
25
>>> foo(2)
55
>>> foo(2)
55
>>> foo(2)
55
>>> foo(3)
99
>>> foo(3)
99
>>> foo(3)
99
>>>
```